# Setting value inside struct while using Enum.map

Tags: elixir

Lets assume that I've such struct:

```
results = %{page: page_numer, period: period, result: [%Entry{}, %Entry{}]}
```

And I want to append some data to each %Entry{} in result.result like that with it:

```
result.result
|> Enum.map(fn entry -> 
   entry.page = results[:page]
   entry.period = results[:period]
 end)
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the Map update syntax (assuming you have `:page` and `:period` fields in the `Entry` struct):

```
new_result = result.result
|> Enum.map(fn entry ->
  %{entry | page: results[:page], period: results[:period]}
end)
```

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way would be to use the `Kernel.struct/2` function (or the safer alternative `struct!` that raises on unknown keys)

```
result.result
|> Enum.map(&struct!(&1, page: results[:page], period: results[:period]))
```

Comment: There is a missing bracket in that answer but after adding it it also works!

Comment: Fixed. Yes, the solution provided by @Dogbert is a better one.